# PowerBI: How to display/filter row tables between 2 years dynamically

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, dax

I was wondering if there's a way where I can filter out my table results based on two years. My table A has date column and many miscellaneous columns. So currently I would like the table A to display January 2018 (or 1/1/2018) and December 2019 (or 12/31/2019 --basically ongoing) information. However, once January 1st, 2020 appears, I would like my table A to display row results between January 2019 and December 2020. Is there a way I can do so? Maybe in DAX or clicking some filter option? Could someone show me? I'm still fairly new to PowerBI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to meet this requirement is usually using the Relative Date Slicer or Filter functionality:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range

Not sure if any of those options will meet your scenario. Maybe **Last 12 Months (Calendar)**? Your requirements description didnt make much sense to me - you probably need to explain "ongoing" and "appears".

If the Relative Date functions dont meet your needs, then you'll need to construct a column (in Power Query or DAX) that returns a static value you can use in a Slicer or Filter.